# Jitsi meet flutter build failing due to com.facebook.react

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, jitsi-meet

Trying to implement [Jitsi_meet package](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet) , On app build getting merge error given below ,

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProjectDexDebug'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> > Type com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments is defined multiple times:
> > /Users/sajansj/StudioProjects/inhouse/build/app/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/584ba66c00dd915f0cb76898c276e06ba469cc05465b4dc71376b308058a70ca_1.jar:classes.dex,
> > /Users/sajansj/StudioProjects/inhouse/build/app/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/debug/out/3053a9ec0daa675847b7c2389366f19add1c378d7802c2c42d063b656e840c34_1.jar:classes.dex

Below are my dependent packages , seems one of them is already having `Type com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments` , coudnt figure which and how to exclude the duplicates,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.4
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.0

  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.8.0
  get: ^3.26.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.8.1
  flutter_country_picker: ^0.1.6
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.3
  file_picker: ^3.0.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  gradient_text: ^1.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.1
  http: ^0.13.1
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.2
  stripe_payment: ^1.0.10
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  photo_view: ^0.10.3
  fab_circular_menu: ^1.0.1
  better_player: ^0.0.50
  linkify: ^4.0.0
  polls: ^0.2.2
  readmore: ^1.0.1
  uni_links: ^0.4.0
  flutter_switch: ^0.2.0
  encrypt: ^5.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.1.7+1
  image_downloader: ^0.20.1
  video_thumbnail: ^0.2.5+1
  dio: ^4.0.0
  focused_menu: ^1.0.5
  giphy_picker: ^2.0.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.1.0
  jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0

  flutter_link_previewer: ^1.0.4
  device_info: ^2.0.0
  assets_audio_player: ^3.0.3+2
```

Adding flutter doctor -v data ,

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at /Users/sajansj/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (5 weeks ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sajansj/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/sajansj/Library/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/sajansj/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM N950F (mobile)           • 988ad036454256553830 • android-arm64  • Android 9 (API 28)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554        • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.128

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hey did you find any solution ?